# How do I copy a folder full of images to my github repo?

Tags: github

I am trying to push my project to github using terminal. It adds all the files I got except for the folder that contains images. How can I make it add the img folder too?
Thanks for helping everyone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`git add img` should add your images in your staging area. You can confirm that with a `git status`, where your img/ folder should be in the "Staged" section (usually colored in green).

Once staged, you need to commit with `git commit`, and then push to github with `git push origin` (change `origin` to your github remote's name if you gave it another name)

Edit: you can also verify that your `img` folder is not present in the `.gitignore` file. Otherwise, git would ignore the entire folder.